# C# LINQ Plot Graph Data grouped by week

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to take a given date range (`fromDate`, `toDate`) and graph the results by 7 day periods.

My problem is, Where there are no results for a given time period i still need to graph a result object for it, so that i have a full timeline.

My `Entity` that has a DateTime field called `DateCreated` and this is what i need to group by.

I've looked at numerous example on here for grouping by week, but this has a given date range which is making it harder to accomplish.

Comment: you can group your data by week number with Calendar.GetWeekOfYear, and then fill missed data points by iterating from "fromDate" to "toDate" with 7-day step.

Comment: Why dont you just iterate through days/hours and check if the `Entity`(s) were created in that date ?

Comment: You could start with sequence of required dates and then group join it with real data.

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin how do i join the two tables on a a range?

Comment: For day range it will be group join by composite key of DayOfYear and Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue with the following method :-

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, int> GetDataWeekly(IQueryable<Entity> entities, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            var graphData = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

            var weekValues = entities.GroupBy(o => new
            {
                Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", o.DateCreated),
                Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", o.DateCreated)
            }).ToDictionary(o=> o.Key, o=>o.Count());

            var currentWeekDateTime = from;

            while (currentWeekDateTime < to)
            {
                var total = 0;

                var currentWeekNumber = GetWeekOfYear(currentWeekDateTime);

                var generatedKey = new
                {
                    Year = (int?)currentWeekDateTime.Year,
                    Week = (int?)currentWeekNumber
                };


                if (weekValues.ContainsKey(generatedKey))
                {
                    total = weekValues[generatedKey];
                }

                graphData.Add(currentWeekDateTime, total);

                currentWeekDateTime = currentWeekDateTime.AddDays(7);
            }

            return graphData;

        }
```

Comment: You should add (from, to) condition as Where in yours query so that to not pool to much unnecessary data from DB.

Comment: Apologies, theres a line of code missing from here where the filtering is perfoemed before the grouping.

Comment: And need to say that what you are doing in a loop is actually left outer join with a sequence.